# Is it usual for men to use な instead of ね?

Tags: particles, colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles

I was surprised when in this video:

https://youtu.be/m9rf63DsN-s?t=2m44s

I heard ごめんな instead of ごめんね.

Is this because men ten to use な instead of ね? So maybe men would say, for example, 怖いな instead of 怖いね?

Comment: this is anecdotal, but a Japanese friend was just talking about the same thing the other day... That men tend to use な and women tend to use ね.

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot To complicate things more, this little girl says: 大好きな ... then corrects herself and says 大好きです.

https://youtu.be/r6UZFkrv9-E?t=6m7s

Comment: @alex It's different な. She was just trying to speak 大好きな (noun) and then rephrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

な and ね are semantically the same. In other words, な could be used instead of ね and vice versa. However, it feels rough, casual and intimate when you cast it to others. Men tend to be comfortable at that point.